# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'touches') at HTMLElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Не работают функции touchstart и touchend. Назначил ее: что бы при открытии слайде открывался навбар, после слайд влево(если разница в 100px). Не работает, помогите

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changedTouches')
at HTMLElement.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'touches')
at HTMLElement.

html:

```
<nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar__wrap">
                            <div class="hamb">
                                <div class="hamb__field" id="hamb"> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> </div>
                            </div> <img src="images/zhlad.png" alt="" class="logo">
                            <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                                <li><a href="bmz.html">БМЗ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="museum.html">Музей</a></li>
                                <li><a href="cor.html">Ледовый дворец</a></li>
                                <li><a href="usadba.html">Усадьба</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="popup" id="popup"></div>
                <!-- greeting  -->
                <section id="page-hero">
                    <div class="head-site-inner">
                        <h1 id="love" class="heading h-01">Я <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> жлобин</h1>
                        <section id="example" class="sub-header copy-02"> Пульс города на Днепре </section>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

js:

```
const hamb = document.querySelector("#hamb");
const popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
const body = document.body;
const tch = document.querySelector("#page-hero");
let condition = true;

// Клонируем меню, чтобы задать свои стили для мобильной версии
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu").cloneNode(1);

// При клике на иконку hamb вызываем ф-ию hambHandler
let start = 0;
let end = 0;
hamb.addEventListener("click", hambHandler);

tch.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
  start = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  console.log(start);
});
tch.addEventListener("touchend" , function (event) {
  end = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  if (end - start >= 100 && condition) {
      hambHandler();
  } else if (start - end >= 100 && !condition) {
      closeOnClick();
  }
});



// Выполняем действия при клике ..
function hambHandler(e) {
  let condition = false;
  e.preventDefault();
  // Переключаем стили элементов при клике
  popup.classList.toggle("open");
  hamb.classList.toggle("active");
  body.classList.toggle("noscroll");
  renderPopup();
}

// Здесь мы рендерим элементы в наш попап
function renderPopup() {
  popup.appendChild(menu);
}

// Код для закрытия меню при нажатии на ссылку
const links = Array.from(menu.children);

// Для каждого элемента меню при клике вызываем ф-ию
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", closeOnClick);
});

// Закрытие попапа при клике на меню
function closeOnClick() {
  let condition = true;
  popup.classList.remove("open");
  hamb.classList.remove("active");
  body.classList.remove("noscroll");
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

а что за event.originalEvent? это ж прикол из квери, если память не изменяет. а у вас квери нет от слова совсем. вроде должно быть просто event.changedTouches[0].pageX
и event.touches[0].pageX

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вы мне ответили в тг, спасибо - помогли)